# How to assign a class to divs based on a calulcated number

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to assign a class to a div based on a variable?

My example code:

```
<button id="prev-item">Calculate</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"><div class="current">item 1</div></div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
</div>
```

Example JS:

```
$("#prev-item").on("click", function(){
  var firstcal = $('.main').children().length;
  var actual = firstcal - 7
});
```

The code I provided counts how many divs there are in `.main` and stores the number in `firstcal` and then `actual` takes the number in `firstcal` and subtracts 7 from it. In this example, it's 3.

I'm looking for a way to assign a class called `.scroll` to `.items` based on the number in the variable `actual`. So in this example, assign `.scroll` to the first three items in `.main` (item 1, item 2, item 3).

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/openbayou/xfa34qup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through it using `.each` which gets parameter `index` indicating the index of the element being loop then check if the iterating element index is less than the `actual` (maximum) index.

```js
$("#prev-item").on("click", function(){
  var $children = $('.main').children();
  var firstcal = $children.length;
  var actual = firstcal - 7
  $( "span" ).text( actual );
  
  // reset for previously added class
  // $children.removeClass('scrollup')
  
  $children.each(function (i) {
    if (i < actual) {
      $(this).addClass('scrollup')
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.current {color:red}
.item {padding: 7px}
.main {height:265px;overflow:auto}
.scrollup {border-left:5px solid blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="prev-item">Calculate</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"><div class="current">item 1</div></div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: @jwatts1980 You can try to run the snippet tho. It should show up if errors occur. Anyway, the `this` reference inside `each` callback function does belong to the iterating element which is equal to the second param its giving on as you pointed out.

Comment: Whoops. You're right. I misread the the code. I'll kill that comment and +1

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you wished for. It takes the amount of divs with the class "Item" and subtracts 7 from that number. Then assigns class "scroll" to the first (totalNumberOfDivs-7) divs and leave the rest as they are

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#prev-item").click(function(){ //On button click
                var numberOfDivs = 0; //Set total number of divs
                var thisDivNumber = 0; //Set current div

                $(".item").each(function(){ //Figure out how many divs there are
                    numberOfDivs = numberOfDivs+1 //Add them up one by one
                });
                var assignClassToThese = numberOfDivs-7 //Total number of divs minus 7
                $(".item").each(function(){ //Loop through the divs to see which ones to assign the class to
                    thisDivNumber = thisDivNumber+1 
                    if(thisDivNumber<=assignClassToThese){ //If this div number is less than or equal to the number of divs minus 7, then add class
                        $(this).addClass("scroll"); 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<button id="prev-item">Calculate</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"><div class="current">item 1</div></div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
  <div class="item">item 11</div>
</div>
```